# Sql on handling blanks

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query, in that I take the average of the value for that group, and mark it in Average Column for that group. Now if for a group in input, has blanks, it should not calculate the average, and the output should be just left blank.
How should I do this so that even those blanks get handled?

I tried this:
select avg(value) over (partition by "Group") from table

[image: This is a sample input and output]

Comment: What did you try so far? How does your current Query look like?

Comment: select avg(value) over (partition by "Group") from table

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible, Verificable example of your issue.Sample data, your query, expected results by editing the question and not as a comment to the question

Comment: And how does the output of your query look like?

Comment: IT throws an error saying spaces cannot be processed

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense. Are you trying to get an average of a text column? You can calculate an average on numbers only, so you should have a numeric column. Maybe you made a mistake when creating the table?

Comment: And if you get an error, why don't you tell us in your problem description? Show the query, show the error message (and optimally the create table statement). So we know what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG` calculates the average of a set of numbers. So there can be no blanks (white space) in that column, but `NULL`.

`AVG` ignores all `NULL` values, which is not what you want it to do, because for a set of `2, 4, NULL`, you want the result `NULL` and not `(2 + 4) / 2 = 2`.

But you can check whether there appears a `NULL` in the set or not. E.g.:

```
select
  grp,
  value,
  case when count(value) over(partition by grp) = count(*) over (partition by grp) then
    avg(value) over (partition by grp)
  else
    null
  end as average_value
from mytable
order by grp;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5783cd10c5d26e1798c2e1b1e022189